# 2 strings that are equal are returning false

Tags: java

I am working on something that should be able to delete nodes from xml files that match a given value so e.g.

if a nodes id is equal to 3 delete it

Here is my problem I am comparing 2 strings one is the string that says what we are looking for and the other is the node value they are both exactly the same yet they are returning false in a .equals()

String i am passing = "James1"
String found = "James1"

There are no differences at all between both of these strings what is going on here?

```
if (value.item(j).getAttributes().getNamedItem("column").getNodeValue().equals(where)) {
    Log.d("DataStore", "Node Value: " + value.item(j).getTextContent() + " length: " + value.item(j).getTextContent().length() + " equal to: " + equalTo + " length: " + equalTo.length());
    if (value.item(j).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase(equalTo)) {
        dataNode.removeChild(rows.item(i));
        count++;
    }
}
```

This line here is where it fails but should be a success

```
if (value.item(j).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase(equalTo)) {
```

Here is what it logs out when it gets that far i can assure you these strings are exactly the same.

```
Node Value: James2 length: 6 equal to: James2 length: 6
```

Comment: Try to print the strings with `#` surrounding them, there might be a space.

Comment: Log the value of `value.item(j).getTextContent()` .

Comment: It is being logged on the line before.  We need to see the output of that though

Comment: Debug your code to ensure `value` really equals `equalTo`, in case it's not a parsing hierarchy issue. Also `trim()` your strings.

Comment: Added the log information.

Comment: Your code tests `value.item(j)`,  but removes `rows.item(i)`.  Is it OK?

Comment: Yes as value is just a value in the row but i need the whole row deleted if a value equals the given value sort of like sql

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide enough data to give a definitive answer.

Add this line before the if that is failing :

```
compareStr( value.item(j).getTextContent(), equalTo);
```

And add this method to your class or an utility class

```
public static void compareStr(Object a, Object b)
{
    if (a==null && b==null)
    {
        System.out.println("Both null");
        return;
    }
    if ( a==null || b==null )
    {
        System.out.println( "1st String is "
                + ( a==null ? "" : "not " )
                + "but 2nd String is "
                + ( b==null ? "" : "not " )
                + "null" );
        return;
    }
    if ( !( a instanceof String) )
    {
        System.out.println( "1st Object is not a String");
        return;
    }
    if ( !( b instanceof String) )
    {
        System.out.println( "2nd Object is not a String");
        return;
    }
    String s = (String)a;
    String t = (String)b;
    if ( s.length()!=t.length() )
    {
        System.out.println( "Lenghts differ");
        return;
    }
    for ( int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i )
    {
        if ( s.charAt(i)!=t.charAt(i) )
        {
            System.out.println( "The character at position " + i + " are different.");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Strings are equal");
}
```

It will tell you what is different in both strings.

If they are still equal then you should consider if the involved methods have side effects.

Change your code to :

```
if (value.item(j).getAttributes().getNamedItem("column").getNodeValue().equals(where)) {
    String s = value.item(j).getTextContent();
    Log.d("DataStore", "Node Value: " + s + " length: " + s.length() + " equal to: " + equalTo + " length: " + equalTo.length());
    compareStr( s, equalTo );
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(equalTo)) {
        dataNode.removeChild(rows.item(i));
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns saying strings are equal, yet the if statement is failing still.

Comment: I missed the possibility that the objects might not be Strings. I've updated my answer, try with the new code.

Comment: It still says the strings are equal I am positive that it cannot be the strings themselves as i have checked over them countless times and assigned them to new strings just to check and it still fails.

Comment: Weird... Maybe side effects? I've updated the answer again.